# Break headers and data to separate fields

Tags: r, csv

I have this data that don't know how to break it to different fields

```
HeaderA.HeaderB.HeaderC
1A,1B,1C
2A,2B,2C
```

Data is read through csv file. I tried something like

```
cSplit(data, "HeaderA", ",")
```

but it didn't work well. It gave me back the result as below without header. The data didn't even separate out to field correctly

```
"A1" "B1"     "C1"
"A2" "B2"     "C2"
```

My goal is to have data like:

```
HeaderA HeaderB HeaderC
1A      1B      1C
2A      2B      2C
```

Can somebody help please?

Comment: what does `read.csv('my.difficult.file', header = FALSE, sep = ',', col.names = c('HeaderA', 'HeaderB', 'HeaderC')) do for you?

Answer (score 2):

One option is a two-step read process: first parse the column names (with entries separated by "."), then read the main data (with entries separated by ","). We can roll this up into a custom `my_read_data` function.

```r
my_read_data <- function(file) {
    
    # Read round 1: reads & splits column names
    data <- readr::read_delim(file, delim = ".", n_max = 0)

    # Read round 2: read data 
    dplyr::bind_rows(
        data, readr::read_csv(file, skip = 1, col_names = names(data)))

}
```

Then for the sample data you give, we have

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
my_read_data("HeaderA.HeaderB.HeaderC
1A,1B,1C
2A,2B,2C")
## A tibble: 2 × 3
#  HeaderA HeaderB HeaderC
#  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
#1 1A      1B      1C     
#2 2A      2B      2C
```

This will also work if you replace sample data with a filename.